# Editing Variable in Wordpress Plugin Using a Function

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to set a variable within a wordpress plugin file, however do not want to edit the plugin file .

The variable that needs to be set is hard coded within the plugin settings file. Currently it is set to a maximum value of 10 using

'max'   => 10,

I need to be able to change it to 'max'   => 1000, but without editing the plugin file directly.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what plugin it is. It might provide a hook which you can call to update the variable. If not, I'm afraid that you will have to edit the plugin code in order to achieve your result.

Comment: Unfortunately they do not provide a hook. Essentially I was hoping to have a function call that plugin php file and set the value of a particular variable defined inside that file.